# Acidic strength comparison between sulphuric acid and nitric acid

Tags: acid-base

Why is $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ more acidic than $\ce{HNO_3}$. Shouldn't it be the other way around because $\ce{N}$ is more electronegative than $\ce{S}$?

My reason: $\ce{O}$ can take electrons more easily from $\ce{S}$ than from $\ce{N}$. Hence, it will be more difficult to remove $\ce{H}$ from $\ce{H2SO4}$ than from $\ce{HNO3}$. Hence, $\ce{HNO3}$ should be more acidic.

Comment: Note that by the Chemistry SE site policy, it is preferred not using MathJax formatting in titles, for indexing/searching reason.

Comment: N is not more electronegative than O !!!

Comment: I think the OP means S, as argued in the second paragraph. Should be a typo.

Comment: What about $\ce{H2SO3 and HNO2}$? If you are just arguing S vs N, they would have the same strength as $\ce{H2SO4 and HNO3}$, respectively.

Comment: @Karsten Theis By analysis of $\ce{^{17}O}$ Raman IR spectroscopy, there has been reportedly detected presence of dissolved SO2 and HSO4-, but no [H2SO3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfurous_acid).  So the equilibrium is like  $\ce{SO2 + H2O <=> HSO3- + H+}$.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing about acidity is the stability of the conjugate base, which is enhanced by resonance effect and inductive effect. The more stable the conjugate base, the easier deprotonation becomes, and thus the stronger the acid.

In a $\ce{NO3^-}$ ion, the negative charge can delocalise among three O atoms, but in a $\ce{HSO4^-}$ ion, in addition to delocalisation among three O atoms, there is an additional OH group, which further stabilises the anion by inductive effect. So $\ce{HSO4^-}$ is the more stable conjugate base, and $\ce{H2SO4}$ is a stronger acid than $\ce{HNO3}$.

Comment: According to my argument, since O can easily take electrons from S, O will have a partially -ve charge. Due to this, H+ will be difficult to release and hence $\ce{H2SO4}$ should be less acidic. But I do understand the first reason so that's fine.

Comment: No that's not correct. One should not consider the attraction between the partial -ve charge on O and H+, but instead should consider the O-H bond strength. The more -ve O becomes, the less electrons it needs from H, and the weaker the O-H bond, so H actually can escape more easily.

Comment: But in that case, H- will be released not H+...

Comment: Then maybe I'm unable to rationalize your original idea. Answer edited to remove that part.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my method for looking at it:

> For determining acidity, we need to look which one of $\ce{H2SO4}$ or $\ce{HNO3}$ form a more stable anion after the $H+$ is extracted.

Lets condsider $\ce{H2SO4}$ first-
[image]
• There are two sites to extract a proton.

• After a proton is removed, the $O-$ is in resonance with *2* oxygen atoms attached to the sulfur atom.

Now, in $\ce{HNO3}$ -
[image]
• There is one site to extract proton

• After removal of $H+$ , there are two resonance structures but the eletrons of the oxygen that lost a proton have delocalised only once and over a shorter region as compared to $\ce{H2SO4}$

Generally, a compound with more resonating structures is more stable due to more charge distribution. Amongst other factors like electronegativity, resonance usually dominates.

Fun fact:
$\ce{H2SO4}$ is stronger acid than $\ce{HNO3}$ , this is shown by following reaction:
$\ce{H2SO4} + \ce{HNO3} ---> \ce{NO2+} + \ce{HSO4-} + \ce{H2O}$
This reaction is used in the nitration of benzene to form the electrophile.

Answer (score -3):

I do believe that H2SO4 is stronger than HNO3 because also keep in mind that the  H-A bond here in H2SO4 acid is weaker. Why? Because it is one period downwards of N meaning that it has more atomic radius causing it to dissociate more than HNO3. But not much more because the difference is just one period.

Here is a link if you want to check:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiqiuCN09_4AhUH7xoKHbOSCkYQFnoECAMQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.chem.ubc.ca%2Fcourseware%2FpH%2Fsection10%2Findex.html&usg=AOvVaw15gIWrcUwXxHgTZ7jzknQn